# Azure DevOps CLI login ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, github-actions, azure-cli

I am using GitHub Actions to use the Azure CLI and then add the `azure-devops` to my YAML so that I can run some Azure DevOps commands.

I am facing a login issue with the supplied token I provided. This PAT has read and write permissions granted for my organization as well.

```yaml
- name: Set up Azure CLI
  uses: azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    inlineScript: |
      az extension add --name azure-devops
      echo ${{ secrets.ADO_PAT }} | az devops login --organization ${{ secrets.ORG }}
```

Here is the error:

```
Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.54.0
ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.
Error: Error: az cli script failed.
cleaning up container...
```

Comment: Would https://github.com/Azure/login not work for your use case?

Comment: Is that same token working for you from your local command line? Please verify and add that in your question. If that works, try quoting `'${{...}}'` in your workflow and test again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following to fix the issue:

1. Ensure the Azure DevOps PAT is valid and not expired. Also ensure the user of the PAT has the access to the Azure DevOps organization.
2. Ensure the value of parameter '**`--organization`**' on the '**`az devops login`**' command is correct. You need to provide the complete URL of the organization (**`https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}`**), not only the organization name.

   ```bash
   az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}
   ```

Comment: @greg, Is there any update from you?